# Как сделать шаблонный компонент в React/MUI, добавляя в ручную нужные данные

Tags: reactjs, mui

Не понимаю как реализовать следующий функционал:
Верхняя переменная RadioAtom код представляет собой "атом", который в последствии экспортируется в "молекулу"

```
export const RadioAtom = ([{label, defaultChecked}]) =>   <FormControlLabel  control={<Radio />} label="#" defaultChecked="#" />
```

Как сделать чтобы было следующее:
При экспорте атома в молекулу я мог задавать в массиве объектов параметры радиокнопок, и они появлялись с нужными мне значениями на странице

```
<RadioGroup 
    RadioAtom={[
        {name: что-то, label: что-то, defaultChecked: true/false},
        {name: что-то2, label: что-то2, defaultChecked: true/false2}
    ]}          
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Допустим это ваш массив с данными

```
const dataRender = [
        {name: что-то, label: что-то, defaultChecked: true},
        {name: что-то2, label: что-то2, defaultChecked: false}
    ]
```

Компонент `RadioAtom` будет принимать параметр `data` и с помощью метода `.map()` возвращать массив **JSX** элементов(`FormControlLabel`):

```
  export const RadioAtom = ({data}) => {
    data.map(item => 
      <FormControlLabel 
        control={<Radio/>} 
        label={item.label} 
        defaultChecked={item.defaultChecked}
      />
  }
```

Теперь в `RadioGroup` добавим компонент `RadioAtom` где указывается передаваемый параметр `data` и его значение:

```
<RadioGroup>
    <RadioAtom data={dataRender} />
</RadioGroup>
```